# Read random line from file also imports a \n?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So my code is :

```js
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){
        data += "";
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        randomLineN = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)
        randomString = lines[randomLineN];
        uploader=""
        fs.readFile("./uploaders.txt", function(err, data){
            data += '';
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            uploader = lines[randomLineN];
            msg.reply("Enjoy this random clip submitted by : {0} [{1}]".format(uploader,randomString))
        })
    })
```

But when I execute that, it shows: 
http://prntscr.com/srlpma
And I do not want there to be a new line! I want all this in one line... How though?
(I tried "uploader.replace(/\n/g, '')", dosen't work though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `randomString`.

Try

```js
randomString.replace(/\n/g, '')
```

or for better

```js
randomString.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')
```